# Connectedness in logic?

Tags: general-topology, logic

Topological compactness has a logical interpretation when we consider the theorem of compactness which says that if a set of sentences has a model, then every finite subset of it also has a model, and vice-versa. Is there some similar result when we consider connectedness?

Comment: Well, these two definitions of 'compactness' are not connected that strongly..

Comment: @Berci The compactness theorem is *exactly* the statement that the space of complete satisfiable theories (topologized by taking as a basis sets of the form $[\varphi] = \{T\mid \varphi\in T\}$) is a compact topological space.

Comment: The google search ["topological model theory" + "connected"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22topological+model+theory%22+%22connected%22&filter=0) might provide something, but I haven't looked through the search results.